# What caused the leaf discoloration in my Kaffir lime?

Tags: plant-care, diseases, leaves, fungus, discoloration

The leaves of my kaffir lime plant have the grainy discoloration which looks like a disease. I assume normal leaves would be plain dark green. I didn't see insects or aphids living or staying in the plant, just this discoloration. It receives direct sunlight around 10 am to 3 PM daily.

Can you help identify what caused this discoloration? Could it be caused by a fungus? What should I do to make it produce a healthy green color?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a natural variegation. Mosaic virus has yellow blotches with vague edges. This looks to have sharp edges so not a problem.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variegation

Yellow mostly between the veins can be bad (Citrus variegated chlorosis - a bacterial infection).

Comment: Could this be nutrient deficiency?

Comment: Not to give a blotchy effect like this.

Comment: It had dark green leaves when I bought the plant though.

Comment: To be really sure, do you have a photo on the  most affected leaf?